# Construct a list of integers that satisfy a biased condition

Tags: number-theory

Given $n\geq1$ integer, find list of integers $x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots , x_n$ and $m$ such that :

1 ) $x_i = O(2^{n^3})$  for all $1\leq i \leq n$

2 ) $m = O(n^{12})$

3 ) for all $a_i \geq 0$ integers and $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i = n$

then $m | \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i $ iff $a_i=1$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$

So given $n$ can we always construct such a list $x_1,...,x_n,m$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? You have enough reputation to know that such PSQ's are not appreciated here.

Comment: @Servaes what does PSQ stand for?

Comment: I'm reading this question carefully and it seems that $x_1= \cdots = x_n =1$ and $m=n$ works. Does this trivial solution satisfy you?

Comment: No, because if we take a1 =0 and a2=2 then this will give 2x2+x3+...=m but its not good since m must divide only (if and only if) all ai =1 and just in that case @Crostul

Comment: @Ahmad I see. This argument shows that all $x_i$s must be distinct. Can you provide some examples you already found for small $n$? For example for $n=2$ we can have $x_1=1, x_2=2, m=3$. Did you find other small examples for small $n$?

Comment: @Crostul for small n less than 30 you can find many such examples but its not intresting before n becomes large number in the millions so i am looking for general idea, i tried solving it mod primes or prime powers.

Comment: @DavidRaveh A Problem Statement Question; a question that simply states a problem without any context, sources or own efforts. See meta for more details on policy:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq

Comment: Adjusting $x_i$ by $m$ changes nothing, so you can enforce that $|x_i|<m$, so condition (1) follows from condition (2).

Comment: One simple general solution (ignoring condition (2)) is $x_i=(n+1)^{i-1}$, $m=\sum x_i$. Not sure how much better you can do than $m=O(n^n)$. What’s the best you’ve found?

Comment: @Ahmad - What do you mean by $O$? I would assume https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation but that doesn’t make sense once you’ve fixed $n$. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: @DaanMichiels yes, big o notation, so $m$ does not grow up more than polynomialy as Eric pointed in the comment, an expoentital solution is easy to find.

Comment: Where does this problem come from ? Why $n^{12}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it doesn't exist. Even if you replace the conditions with those weaker ones :

$1)$ No condition on the $x_i$,

$2)$ $m = \mathrm{o}\!\left(\frac{2^n}{n}\right)$,

$3)$ For all integers $(a_i)$ between $0$ and $2$ whose sum equals $n$, then $m\mid\sum_{i = 1}^n a_ix_i$ if and only if each $a_i$ equals $1$.

Indeed, assume it exists, then for $n$ large enough, we can find $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,m)$ that satisfy condition $3)$ and $m < \frac{2^n}{n}$. Let for all $i$, $y_i$ be the remainder of the Euclidean division of $x_i$ by $m$. In particular, each $y_i$ is less or equal than $m - 1$. Let $S$ be their sum. We have $m|S$ because $m$ divides the sum of the $x_i$ and $S \leqslant n\max\{y_i\} \leqslant (m - 1)n \leqslant 2^n - n \leqslant 2^n - 2$.

Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ the set of the subsets of $[\![1,n]\!] = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and define,
$$
\varphi : \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} \mathcal{P}_n & \rightarrow & [\![0,S]\!] \\ I & \mapsto & \displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} y_i \end{array}\right.
$$
We have $\#\mathcal{P}_n = 2^n$ and $\#[\![0,S]\!] = S + 1 \leqslant 2^n - 1$ thus $\varphi$ is not injective by the pigeonhole principle, which implies that it exists some $I \neq J$ included in $[\![1,n]\!]$ such that $\varphi(I) = \varphi(J)$. When $A \cap B = \emptyset$ for $A$ and $B$ in $\mathcal{P}_n$, we have $\varphi(A \cup B) = \varphi(A) + \varphi(B)$ so $\varphi(I) = \varphi(I\backslash J) + \varphi(I \cap J)$ and $\varphi(J) = \varphi(J\backslash I) + \varphi(I \cap J)$.

We deduce that $\varphi(I') = \varphi(J')$ where $I' = I\backslash J$ and $J' = J\backslash I$. Notice that $I' \cap J' = \emptyset$ and at least one of them is non empty because $I \neq J$ (actually, it implies that both of them is non empty). It allows us to define for all $i$, $a_i = 0$ if $i \in I'$, $a_i = 2$ if $i \in J'$ and $a_i = 1$ else. $I' \neq \emptyset$ and $J' \neq \emptyset$ imply that it exists at least one $a_i \neq 1$.

We have,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^n a_iy_i - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i & = \sum_{i = 1}^n (a_i - 1)y_i\\
& = \sum_{i \in I'} -y_i + \sum_{i \in J'} y_i\\
& = -\varphi(I') + \varphi(J')\\
& = 0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_iy_i = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i = S$ is divisible by $m$ hence $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_ix_i \equiv \sum_{i = 1}^n a_iy_i \equiv S \equiv 0\, [m]$, which is a contradiction.